# I need to get m2e plugin options for my new project too when I do right-click on it

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2e, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I installed `m2e plugin` in my SpringSourceToolSuite IDE, for one of my projects, when i right-click on a project, iam able to see m2e install, clean options..

BUT for my recent project, I just converted normal web project to maven, BUT when i right-click on my new project, iam unable to see m2e install, clean options..

**Can anyone please tell me what could be the reason?  I need to get m2e plugin options for my new project too when I do right-click on it..**

Answer (score 0):

Delete your project inside of the IDE (not the contents). Then run File - Import - Maven Projects and choose the location of your project.

As far as i know, its not possible to add maven project nature to an existing project inside of eclipse workspace.